# How to solve - FMUException: The slave failed to initialize

Tags: python, fmi, jmodelica, assimulo

I am new to the FMU world and started with it. I am trying to load and simulate an FMU in python which is created in GT-Suite. I had hard time solving the errors while loading an FMU but could do it finally.I am following [jmodelica tutorials](https://jmodelica.org/pyfmi/tutorial.html#)

```
from pyfmi import load_fmu

#Load the FMU
model = load_fmu('AHU.fmu')

#simulate an fmu
res = model.simulate(final_time=10)
```

Now I am getting an error when I try to simulate the model. Error is:

```
FMUException: The slave failed to initialize. See the log for possibly more information.
```

What could be the reason? Is there something wrong in my .fmu file because when I try to do load and simulate a fmu downloaded from [fmi-standard](https://fmi-standard.org/downloads/) everything works fine.

```
model = load_fmu('RoomHeating_OM_RH.fmu')

res = model.simulate(final_time=10)
```

`'RoomHeating_OM_RH.fmu'` is from [fmi-standard](https://fmi-standard.org/downloads/)

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: `FMIL: module = b'Slave', log level = 2: b'[error][FMU status:Error] fmiInitializeSlave: Illegal call sequence.` @ChristianWinther

Comment: Ok, that is interesting. I would recommend to test the FMU using the compliance checker available from the FMI standard homepage to verify that the FMU is correct.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianWinther some problem with my fmu. Its resolved now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with FMU exported from GT-Suite. Apparently, GT-Suite doesn't support fmu for model-exchange. It works only for co-simulation